# Laravel 5.8 VerifyCsrfToken Exception not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to exclude all requests on an endpoint which I call test.com/code so I do like this in the VerifyCsrfToken.php file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'code',
        'code/*'
    ];
}
```

But it does not solve the issue, even after I try to run "php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear", Anyone knows why I can't exclude specific routes? (Laravel 5.8)

My route is something like this:

```
Route::get('code/testing', 'CodeController@testing');
```

I have try this and it didn't work either.

```
protected $except = [
        'https://test.com/code/*',
    ];
```

Till now the only way I figure out is remove the line "\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class," from app/Http/Kernel.php to disable Csrf feature which is not a good solution.

Comment: show your hitting url

Comment: I'm hitting mydomain.com/code/testing

Comment: seems all good with it try with clearing the cache

Comment: I have try clear the cache but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use `/` (slash) at the beggining :

```
protected $except = [
        '/code/*'
    ];
```

Comment: Do you pass the `@csrf` from blade?

Comment: No, I didn't pass that

Answer (score 0):

You can try `'/code/*'`. It works for me with a slash `/` in the front of the url.